# No module named soundfile

Tags: python, pip, python-2.x

Whenever I try to import `soundfile` I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named soundfile
```

I installed pysoundfile seemingly without trouble:

```
$ sudo pip install pysoundfile
The directory '~/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '~/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pysoundfile
  Downloading PySoundFile-0.9.0.post1-py2.py3.cp26.cp27.cp32.cp33.cp34.cp35.cp36.pp27.pp32.pp33-none-macosx_10_5_x86_64.macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (573kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 573kB 430kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=0.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pysoundfile)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=0.6->pysoundfile)
Installing collected packages: pysoundfile
Successfully installed pysoundfile-0.9.0.post1
```

so what's causing this problem?

Comment: Does the `python` executable you're using match the `pip` executabel you're using?

Comment: Pip install by default install package for python 2.7. Are you usinh Python 2.7?

Comment: @Evert I ran `which` on both, got `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Not sure how to check if it's the same for `sudo`, but running `sudo which` returned the same. That might not be the correct way to diagnose though.

Comment: @HonzaSedloň Python 2.7.13, pip 9.0.1

Comment: Search the module file (use `find`). Then see if the _ancestor-library-path_ is included in `sys.path`

Comment: @MayraDelgado where's the module file?

Comment: It's weird that something in `/usr/local` wants to install things in `/Library/Python`. Who has permissions to `/usr/local/`? Root, admin or your normal user account? Also, how did you install that Python version in the first place? The path suggests Homebrew, and Homebrewn Python/pip would never install anything in `/Library/Python`.

Comment: @Evert I don't know

Comment: Well, you should be able to find out the permissions easily: `ls -la /usr/local` should already tell you. And if there's a `/usr/local/Homebrew/` directory, it's likely all installed by Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

For Google Colab Research

copy paste this

```
!pip install soundfile
```

& then import it

```
import soundfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if it is installed in a test environment

**Example Ways**

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ python -m virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install pysoundfile
$ python
>>> import soundfile
```

Answer (score 2):

PySoundFile depends on the Python packages CFFI and NumPy, and the system library libsndfile.

To install the Python dependencies, I recommend using the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.

This will come with all dependencies pre-installed. To install the dependencies manually, you can use the conda package manager, which will install all dependencies using `conda install cffi numpy` (conda is also available independently of Anaconda with `pip install conda`).

With CFFI and NumPy installed, you can use `pip install pysoundfile` to download and install the latest release of PySoundFile. On Windows and OS X, this will also install the library libsndfile. On Linux, you need to install libsndfile using your distribution's package manager, for example `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I guess the problem is with python versions. When I tried with *Python 3.5.2*

```
python3 file_name.py
ImportError: No module named 'soundfile'
```

Instead, I tried the same with *Python 2.7.12*

```
python file_name.py
```

It successfully imported it!

Answer (score 0):

when I try to use this commend `conda install -c conda-forge soundfile`, it does not work.
after that, I utilize the `pip install soundfile`, it is okay for me.